Is there a way to nest an arrow::Array in apache arrow?
I want to create a struct similar to the result I obtain when I use the hash_distinct aggregate compute function.
For eg, the result of perform hash_distinct on a record batch is as follows (where a is a grouping key):
a: string
hash_distinct(b): struct<hash_distinct: list<item: string>>
  child 0, hash_distinct: list<item: string>
      child 0, item: string
----
a:
  [
    [
      "2"
    ]
  ]
hash_distinct(b):
  [
    -- is_valid: all not null
    -- child 0 type: list<item: string>
      [
        [
          "19",
          "22",
          "25"
        ]
      ]
  ]

Now if I have an arrow::Array of elements [1, 7, 3], how do I create a struct similar to the one above.
Basically I want a ListArray where the first and only element in the ListArray is [1, 7, 3]. The reason I'm asking for a nested ListArray is because I believe this is the first step to creating the desired struct but do correct me if I'm wrong.
Can provide more details if this isn't clear enough.
Edit:
I've found a solution from the arrow library that works but looping over the list might not be the most efficient.
template <typename T>
Result<std::shared_ptr<::arrow::Array>> nested_list_builder(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> elements) {
  std::shared_ptr<::arrow::Array> nested_elements;
  ::arrow::MemoryPool* pool = ::arrow::default_memory_pool();
  ::arrow::ListBuilder builder(pool, std::make_shared<T>(pool));
  auto* item_builder = (static_cast<T*>(builder.value_builder()));
  auto status = builder.Append();
  for(size_t i = 0; i < elements->length(); i++) {
    auto scalar = elements->GetScalar(i).ValueOrDie();
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(item_builder->AppendScalar(*scalar));
  }
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(builder.Finish(&nested_elements));

  return std::move(nested_elements);
}

